# How to translate code from Lisp (MIT Schema) into JavaScript using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lisp, ramda.js, mit-scheme

I'm currently teaching myself functional programming.

I'm trying to translate the following:

```
(define a 3)
(define b (+ a 1))

(* (cond ((> a b) a)
         ((< a b) b)
         (else -1))
   (+ a 1))
```

into JavaScript (using Ramda).

One could use nested ternaries, but I like to using the `cond` function from Ramda. Here is what I did:

```
const a = 3;
const b = 3 + 1;

cond([[() => a > b, () => a], [() => a < b, () => b], [T, () => -1]])() * (a + 1)
```

The problem I have with this is that I had to use these functions (e.g. `() => 3`) instead of just their value (e.g. `a`).

Is there any way to avoid these functions? Or is there another better way of doing this in JavaScript (maybe even without Rambda)?

I would like to avoid statements such as `if`, `for` and `switch`.

An alternative way to solve this would be using:

```
import gt from "ramda/src/gt";
import lt from "ramda/src/lt";

const a = () => 3;
const b = () => a() + 1;


cond([[gt(a, b), a], [lt(a, b), b], [T, () => -1]])() * (a() + 1);
```

Which complicates `a` and `b`, since they will always have to be called (see `a() + 1`).

**EDIT:**

For some reason the last code where I define `a` and `b` as functions doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramda is auto curried, so you can invoke the function with some of the parameters, and get a new function back. For example:

```js
const { pipe, cond, gt, lt, T, always, identity, multiply } = R

const a = 3
const b = 3 + 1

const fn = (a) => pipe(
  cond([
    [gt(a), always(a)],
    [lt(a), identity],
    [T, always(-1)]
  ]),
  multiply(a + 1)
)

const result = fn(a)(b)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you really need the `always(a)`?  Couldn't you also just return `a`?

Comment: @J.Hesters: `cond` accepts an array of pairs of functions, each with the same inputs.  The first in every pair should return a boolean, the second should return the relevant value.  So the `always` is necessary.  `always(a)` is equivalent to `() => a`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @J.Hesters - you're welcome. I've updated the code a bit to make it more pointfree. In addition to Scott's excellent explanation - replace `always` with `console.log`, and you can see what you get.

Comment: @OriDrori Thank you! It's so strange to switch from my (presumably bad) class-like JS style with statements to a more functional style. You have to think completely differently. Is also struggle with point free style, which is why very much appreciate your answer 

Answer (score 2):

I think you're working under a bit of a misapprehension.  `cond` is designed to give you a function.  It's really not designed for creating a scalar value for an expression.  Of course it can do so, simply by immediately calling the function it generates.  But that's not the point of it.  Moreover, it really is not meant for calling with nullary functions (except in the case of passing `T` for the default condition.).  Again, you can do so, but it's working against the grain of the tool.

Although Ramda takes inspiration from both LISP-style and ML-style functional languages, and although I am personally more a fan of the former, Ramda is closer to the ML world, especially to Haskell.  So the main activity it is meant to support is to build functions by composing other functions.

If I were to solve this problem, I probably wouldn't use any Ramda whatsoever, choosing something like this:

```
const larger = (a, b) => (a > b) ? a : (b > a) ? b : -1
const foo = (a, b) => (a + 1) * larger(a, b)

foo(3, 4) //=> 16
foo(6, 3) //=> 42
foo(3, 3) //=> -4
```

Or, if I didn't need to reuse `larger`, I might inline it like this:

```
const foo = (a, b) => (a + 1) * ((a > b) ? a : (b > a) ? b : -1)
```

Of course I can write this in Ramda, and in a point-free fashion:

```
const larger = cond([[gt, unapply(head)], [lt, unapply(last)], [T, always(-1)]])
const foo = converge(multiply, [inc, larger])
```

Or again, I might inline `larger`, or replace `unapply(head)` with `nthArg(0)` and `unapply(last)` with `nthArg(1)`.

But none of these options is as readable as the original.  Ramda adds nothing here that I can see.  Note that I am a big fan of Ramda; I started the library and am one of its principle authors.  But I don't think it should be used for every problem.

Comment: Thank you for your insights! Which library would you recommend? Which would you recommend if you want to be as close to lisp as possible? And which would you recommend for FP in JavaScript in general?

Comment: Also thank you for creating Lambda! I recently discovered FP and I'm reading [this book](https://www.amazon.de/Structure-Interpretation-Computer-Electrical-Engineering/dp/0262510871) to learn it, but it's in Lisp and my main language is JavaScript. Do you have any advice (besides practicing a lot) on how to learn FP with JavaScript?

Comment: I was suggesting that no library is necessary.  I think the plain JS version I suggested is already readable.  If you don't like nested ternary statements, this can obviously be done with `if` statements instead.  A library like Ramda complements vanilla JS.  It is not meant to replace it.

Comment: I think that SICP, which you're reading, is the very best general-purpose introduction to programming book available.  I have two strong recommendations for JS. [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/) by Marijn Haverbeke is a great gentle introduction to the language, and shows both FP and OOP code.  The best introduction to FP JS, as it's most commonly done these days is Dr. Booleans [Mostly Adequate Guide](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't have to wrap everything in thunks (i.e. functions that take no arguments) in Scheme is because `cond` is a macro that expands to nested `if`s, in your case:

```
(if (> a b) a
  (if (< a b) b
    -1))
```

So nope, if you want to avoid ternary operators and wrapping everything in thunks you don't have much of a choice with vanilla JS.

If you don't mind using non-standard JS, you could implement `cond` with a macro with [Sweet.js](https://www.sweetjs.org/doc/tutorial#sweet-cond)...